# InDesign CC : Change pixels with decimals to whole numbers

Tags: adobe-indesign

In InDesign CC, how do you change the pixels to whole numbers? In the Info panel, when I try to resize a rectangle, the Width says 646.845px and Height is 88.992px....it's so hard to work with!

Comment: Are you resizing your rectangle by typing in the info panel, or by clicking and dragging directly on the object?

Comment: Clicking and dragging the object directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the ruler and choose pixels from the dropdown.

[image]

Do this for both the vertical and horizontal rulers, now when you resize the increment of the object will be constrained to even pixels.

Comment: @Xeon No problem!